# Timeout error when reading from USB Multimeter

Tags: python, timeout, usb

I need to extract data from a digital multimeter using a USB connection and Python on my Raspberry Pi. Here I have a very basic Python script for reading from a generic USB device, and note that the idVendor and idProduct variables are correct for the multimeter I am using:

```
import usb.core

dev=usb.core.find(idVendor=0x067b,idProduct=0x2303)
ep=dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
   dev.detach_kernel_driver(i)

dev.set_configuration()
eaddr=ep.bEndpointAddress

r=dev.read(eaddr,1024)
print(len(r))
```

I have a rules file in the path /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbftdi.rules. It has the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x067b", MODE="0666"
```

When I try to execute the file while I have the multimeter turned on connected to my Raspberry Pi, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usbRead.py", line 14, in <module>
    r=dev.read(eaddr,1024)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1024, in read
    self.__get_timeout(timeout))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 869, in intr_read
    timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 954, in __read
    _check(retval)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 602, in _check
    raise USBTimeoutError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBTimeoutError: [Errno 110] Operation timed out


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```